# How can I extract specific values from an array ?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have this variable :

```
var test = sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow(),1,1,sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

Which return me the following result :

```
[[data0, data1, data2, data3, data4, etc...]]
```

Can I convert this array into an array or array `[[data0],[data1],[data2],[data3],etc...]` so I can do something like this `test[1][3]` so select `data1` and `data3` ? Is this the best solution ? If yes, how can I do this ? If no what's the best solution.

Comment: You can use `sheet1.getDataRange().getValues()`. It will convert entire sheet into 2D array and then you can easily use `test[1][3]`.

Comment: Thanks but correct me if I'm wrong. When I'm using `sheet1.getDataRange().getValues()` I have all the data of my sheet. I'm only want to select data in the last row of my sheet... I don't know if I'm clear .

Comment: Yeah I got your point, yes it will select all the data of the sheet, but still you can process only the row which you want by fixing first parameter of test[fix this][]. I don't think this will cause any problems of speed or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getDataRange().getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) to get all the values of the sheet first and assign that to a variable. You can now access that variable like a 2D array. Here's a short snippet to show you.

```
 function main(){
   Logger.log("the value returned was "+ fetchValue(1,1) ); //will fetch the value at index 1,1
}

function fetchValue(row,col) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID_HERE");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

   return data[row][col];
}
```

The `fetchValue` method we've created extracts the value from the specified `row,col` index. Check my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476150/how-to-index-arrays-in-google-apps-script/42485851#42485851) if you want additional reference.